# wp_insert_post inserts 3 posts at once?

Tags: functions, wp-insert-post

I want to write an import of events (that I had as a text).

The post are inserted, but each post is inserted 3 times!?

I'm running a function on `after_setup_theme` in my `functions.php`.

What I do:

1. I refresh to page to run the function
2. The post is inserted. Great.

[image]

3. I comment the code and refresh the page again.
4. Then I see the post being inserted 3 times in total.

[image]

Am I using the wrong hook, something wrong with my code, or what am I missing?

Here's the code:

```
function ekesto_insert_post(){
    $import_array = array();

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test Event',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'  => 'event'
    );
    $new_post_custom_fields = array(
        'category' => 29,
        'date_start' => '20231101',
        'venue_name' => 'Schloss Glarisegg',
        'location' => 'Steckborn (ZH)',
        'organizer_name' => 'Pathways Courses',
        'organizer_url' => 'https://pathways-courses.org/'
    );
    $import_array[] = array($new_post, $new_post_custom_fields);

    foreach ($import_array as $array) {
        // Insert post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($array[0], true); // Use $wp_error set to true for error handling
        // update ACF custom fields
        foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {
            update_field($key, $value, $post_id);
        }
        // Check if there was an error during post insertion
        if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
            // Error occurred while inserting the post
            echo "Error: " . $post_id->get_error_message();
        } else {
            // The post was successfully inserted, and $post_id contains the post ID
            echo "Post inserted successfully. New Post ID: " . $post_id;
        }
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'ekesto_insert_post');
```

Eventually there will be more events.

Appreciate any hint!

Comment: you mention this runs on `after_theme_setup` but there's no code to add to that action in your question, or explanation of what you're trying to do. I can also see there's no code to check if the post already exists before calling `wp_insert_post`. This means every single request to your site will create the posts, frontend requests, AJAX requests, cron jobs, admin pages, even assets that are generated/processed via plugins will trigger this. There is no de-duplication checking in `wp_insert_post` as sometimes you want to insert the same thing multiple times

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @TomJNowell! I wanted to simplify the code, that's why I left it.. but I now added the code as it is in my file. Thanks for the hint on checking if the post already exists, I will try to add this check.. This already helps! I somehow sensed that it is fired on multiple requests, but never thought about checking if a post with a specific title already exists. I was kind of hoping that I simply used the wrong action hook.

Comment: not _multiple_ requests, but _all_ requests of all types, `after_setup_theme` runs on every single request, and can even run in CLI contexts if you use WP CLI. At a minimum I'd at least restrict this code to running if `is_admin` is true, these checks are expensive and you shouldn't be doing DB writes on the frontend if you can avoid it

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I only used the code once to import the posts, now it's disabled.. but I'll add `is_admin` to the code, for a next time. Thanks again!

Comment: in future consider a custom WP CLI command, it'll run faster, bypass time/memory limits and you're guaranteed it will only run when you run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TomJNowell's hint I managed to get it working with a simple check if the post already exists (using the `post_exists` function). This code is included in the `functions.php` file.

Additionally, the loop only runs if called from the backend using the `is_admin` function.

Here's the working example:

```
function ekesto_insert_post(){

    // config
    $post_type = 'event';
    
    // post_exists() is by default only available in the admin, so let's get it in case the page is loaded on the frontend
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php');

    $import_array = array();

    $new_post = array(
        'post_title' => 'Test Event',
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'post_type'  => $post_type
    );
    $new_post_custom_fields = array(
        'category' => 29,
        'date_start' => '20231101',
        'venue_name' => 'Schloss Glarisegg',
        'location' => 'Steckborn (ZH)',
        'organizer_name' => 'Pathways Courses',
        'organizer_url' => 'https://pathways-courses.org/'
    );
    $import_array[] = array($new_post, $new_post_custom_fields);

    // only run code in the backend
    if( is_admin()) {
        foreach ($import_array as $array) {
            // check if post title exists
            $fount_post = post_exists( $array[0]['post_title'],'','',$post_type,'publish');
            // 0 is returned if post doesn't exist yet
            if ($fount_post === 0) {
                // Insert post into the database
                $post_id = wp_insert_post($array[0], true); // Use $wp_error set to true for error handling
                // Fill Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) fields
                foreach ($array[1] as $key => $value) {
                    update_field($key, $value, $post_id);
                }
                // Check if there was an error during post insertion
                if (is_wp_error($post_id)) {
                    // Error occurred while inserting the post
                    echo "Error: " . $post_id->get_error_message();
                } else {
                    // The post was successfully inserted, and $post_id contains the post ID
                    echo "Post inserted successfully. New Post ID: " . $post_id;
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'ekesto_insert_post');
```

Note: The code also adds Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) data using the ACF function `update_field()`.